# How to build a data-structure to support some range queries

Tags: java, python, data-structures, time-complexity

An interval is defined by start and end.

> Given a set of possibly overlapping intervals in a range[say, 0-999],
>   build a data structure to support following range queries in optimal
>   time complexity

.

**Overlap(start, end)** = set of all intervals that overlap with [start, end]

**Within(start, end)** = set of all intervals that lie within [start, end]

Where,

```
Intervals I1[start1, end1], I2[start2, end2] are said to overlap with  each other iff start1<end2 && start2<end1
Interval I1[start1, end1] is said to be within interval I2[start2,end2] iff start1>start2 && end1<end2
```

Comment: @Laurentiu L. Can you elaborate the goal for this question what the resulting data structure should look like?

Comment: @LaurentiuL. I understand that the range queries will return the set of intervals mentioned above. But how the data structure(suppose an Array) would look like? I can write the range query logic but I'm not sure how the data structure would look like. Can you show a sample?

Comment: Some part of the question were missing when I wrote this down first. Now this proves that you guys had no idea what I'm asking for and presumed that I want a solution. You didn't even read my question properly. Please do not comment for no reason.

Comment: What you are trying to build is called an Interval tree ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree ) -an ordered tree data structure to hold intervals. Specifically, it allows one to efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or point.  The wikipedia page has several examples and a 'Searching for all overlapping intervals' solution. Ex. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42008/interval-search-tree , http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-interval-tree/ Note : http://infotechgems.blogspot.ro/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html

Comment: Thanks @LaurentiuL.! I'd never heard of interval trees before. At least now I know where to implement my code!

Comment: Glad i could help. I will post the answer for others who stumble upon this question to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wrote some Scala code to implement this using interval trees!

```
class IntervalSearchTree {
     var root=new IntervalNode(null,null,null,null,null);

  class IntervalNode(var left:IntervalNode,var start:Integer,var end:Integer,var maxEnd:Integer,var right:IntervalNode);

    def add(start:Integer,end:Integer ):Unit={
      var node:IntervalNode=root
      while(node!=null){
        if(end>node.maxEnd)
          node.maxEnd=end
        if (start < node.start) {
                if (node.left == null) {
                    node.left = new IntervalNode(null, start, end, end, null);
                    return;
                }
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                if (node.right == null) {
                    node.right = new IntervalNode(null, start, end, end, null);
                    return;
                }
                node = node.right;
            }
      }
      root =  new IntervalNode(null, start, end, end, null);
    }

    def overlap(start:Integer,end:Integer):Unit={

      var intervalNode:IntervalNode=root;
      while (intervalNode != null) {
         if (intersection(start, end, intervalNode)){
           println(intervalNode.start+"-"+intervalNode.end)
         }
         if (leftSubTree(start, end, intervalNode.left)) {
                intervalNode = intervalNode.left;


            } else {

                intervalNode = intervalNode.right;

            }


      }

    }

    def within(start:Integer,end:Integer):Unit={
        var intervalNode:IntervalNode = root;
        while (intervalNode != null) {
           if (subset(start, end, intervalNode)){
           println(intervalNode.start+"-"+intervalNode.end)
         }
         if (leftSubTree(start, end, intervalNode.left)) {
                intervalNode = intervalNode.left;


            } else {

                intervalNode = intervalNode.right;

            }
        }

    }


    def subset(start:Integer,end:Integer,intervalNode:IntervalNode):Boolean={
      return start<intervalNode.start  && end >intervalNode.end ;
    }

    def intersection(start:Integer,end:Integer,intervalNode:IntervalNode):Boolean={
      return start < intervalNode.end && end > intervalNode.start;
    }

    def leftSubTree(start:Integer,end:Integer,intervalLeftSubtree:IntervalNode):Boolean={
      return intervalLeftSubtree != null && intervalLeftSubtree.maxEnd > start;
    }


    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      var intervalSearchTree=new IntervalSearchTree()
        intervalSearchTree.add(17, 19);
        intervalSearchTree.add(5, 8);
        intervalSearchTree.add(21, 24);
        intervalSearchTree.add(22, 24);
        intervalSearchTree.add(20, 26);
        intervalSearchTree.add(20, 24);
        intervalSearchTree.add(4, 8);
        intervalSearchTree.add(5, 9);
        intervalSearchTree.add(15, 18);
        intervalSearchTree.add(7, 10);
        intervalSearchTree.add(16, 22);

        //Input for testing overlaps 
        println("Overlaps");
        intervalSearchTree.overlap(23, 25);
        //Input for testing overlaps
        println("Within");
        intervalSearchTree.within(4, 25);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data-structure this question addresses is called [**Interval tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) :

> An ordered tree data structure to hold intervals,  it allows one to
>   efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or
>   point.

Two effective approaches:

- using an [augmented tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Augmented_tree)
- using a  [Medial- or length-oriented tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Medial-_or_length-oriented_tree)

The proposed algorithm in the link for searching for all overlapping intervals is expected to be faster than a traditional interval tree (augmented tree) for search operations, adding elements is a little slower.

Various approaches to implementing an interval tree:

- Standford has a [an implementation of IntervalTree](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/IntervalTree.html)  in a general purpose utility package edu.stanford.nlp.util with a lot of useful methods
- [Sample code for an interval tree where Given n closed intervals [ai, bi] it finds all pairs of intervals that overlap  - Algorithms, 4th Edition](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/93intersection/IntervalST.java.html)
- [Another interval tree implementation](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-interval-tree/)

When implementing a solution you should know the [performance of java collections processing](http://infotechgems.blogspot.ro/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html)